# How to ignore a property of instance gets serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I’m using **DataContractSerializer** for serialization/deserialization. I need to ignore a particular property of an instance gets serialized which used as a property in another class. Here I have provided the simple code structure for your references. I have tried **IgnoreDataMember** and **XmlIgnore** attributes, but these not worked.

```
[DataContract(Name ="Sample")]
public class Sample1
{
    [DataMember]
    public Sample2 s2 { get; set; }
}

[KnownType("KnownTypes")]
public class Sample2
{
    [DataMember]
    public Sample3 s3 { get; set; }
}
public class Sample3
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }

    public string property2 { get; set; }

    //No need to serialize this property while serializing "S3" property in "Sample2" class.
    //Is it possible???
    public string property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support conditional serialization of properties out of the box.  See e.g. [ShouldSerialize pattern and DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11394587) and [How can I prevent a datamember from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8010677) and [Custom DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42460674) for details and workarounds.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - The linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer) asks how to *unconditionally* ignore a property.  This question is asking how to *conditionally* ignore a property, specifically when serializing a data object inside another data object.

Comment: Should the property *never* be serialized, or only when wrapped within an instance of `Sample2`?. In other words: should `Sample3.property3` be serialized, if `Sample1` would have a property of `Sample3`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - That was my interpretation of *No need to serialize this property while serializing "S3" property in "Sample2" class.*  Can the OP please confirm?

Comment: @dbc I assumed so also (after your comment), however OP didn´t mention that case explicitely, which is why I didn´t reopen the question until now.

Comment: Hi @HimBromBeere, he asks "Property 3" never be serialized when serializing "S3" data object used by "Sample2".